# Creating a value constant that depends on the template type

Tags: c++, templates, types, conditional-statements, constants

I would like to create a C++ template function which has different constants that get used in the implementation depending on the choice of the template type.

```
#define FLOAT_EPSILON       (0.000001f)
#define DOUBLE_EPSILON      (0.00000000000001)

template <class T> void func(T params)
{
    const T epsilon = ???? // either FLOAT_EPSILON or DOUBLE_EPSILON depending on T
    // do some calculations using epsilon
}

template void func(float params);
template void func(double params);
```

I can't quite work out how to do this best, although I thought of some half-assed ways that work. Can you help?

Comment: How about just using `std::numeric_limits`?

Comment: numeric_limits looks like a possibility, although then I'm working with values that are predefined, rather than my own which are tuned for a particular numerical application, although I imagine I could just scale them as appropriate and accept the given ratio.

Comment: Denis, can you give an example of how decltype can be used to solve this?

Comment: I found that `T my_epsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();` works quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a helper template to choose the epsilon.

```
template <typename T> struct EpsilonChooser;

template <> struct EpsilonChooser<float>
{
    float const value = 0.000001f;
};

template <> struct EpsilonChooser<double>
{
    double const value = 0.00000000000001;
};

template <class T> void func(T params)
{
    const T epsilon = EpsilonChooser<T>::value;
    // do some calculations using epsilon
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [R-Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu) solution will transform to a variable template in C++14, demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ac19f8a9e6476c2) :

```
template <typename T> constexpr T epsilon;

template <> constexpr float  epsilon<float>  = 0.001f;
template <> constexpr double epsilon<double> = 0.000001;
```